# "Order" column in SharePoint 2013 List/Document Library

Tags: sharepoint-server

I'm creating a new SharePoint List/Document library. By default, there is a column named "Order", but I can't make that column display on a Listview.

How can I do that?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Order column is Hidden.

You can unhide it with powershell.

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell

# Change List Schema to unhide order field.
$siteUrl = "http://SITEURL"; # YOUR SITE URL
$listTitle = "TESTLIBRARY"; # YOUR LIBRARY NAME

$web = Get-SPWeb -Identity $siteUrl;
$list = $web.Lists[$listTitle];
$field=$list.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName("Order");
$field.SchemaXml=$field.SchemaXml.Replace('Hidden="TRUE"','Hidden="FALSE"');
Write-Host '-------------------------------------'
Write-Host 'Order field is set to visible in list :  ' $list.Title -foregroundcolor Green -nonewline
Write-Host ' @ ' $siteUrl -foregroundcolor Green
Write-Host '-------------------------------------'
$web.Dispose();
```

And then you can modify view and check it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible ways to do it:

Use additional column
Use ReorderItems functionality

In first case you create additional column "Order" of type Number, and set the view to order by this column.

The second approach is much more interesting. In this case, if you don't want to involve code customizations, you have to use list of type "Links". For links lists, SharePoint provides interface for defining items order:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Unfortunately, there is no way to convert a list from one type to another, thus essentialy you have to recreate your existing list as a Links list if you want this functionality in place.

Answer (score 0):

Click on Library setting.

[image]

Click on View in which you want to show the column

[image]

Select the column which you want to show in view.

[image]

And click "OK".

Comment: the problem is I can't find the "Order" column in this view edit page. Is the "Order" column a hidden column ?